# Ordenar datos internos enviados a Firestore

Tags: android, firebase

Hola estoy trabajando con firebase. A la hora de enviar un registro me llegan los datos desordenados.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Hay algún método para ordenarlos a mi gusto? Ya que quisiera tenerlo en el orden del formulario.

Dejo por las dudas un fragmento de mi código y desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo, password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                USERUID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Clientes").document(USERUID);

                Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                user.put("Nombre y Apellido", nombre);
                user.put("Correo", correo);
                user.put("Domicilio", domicilio);
                user.put("Localidad", localidad);
                user.put("Fecha" , FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.d(TAG, "Cuenta creada, UID de usuario : " + USERUID))
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(TAG, "Creación de cuenta fallida: " + e.toString()));
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerificacionDeDatos.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Light.make(snackbar, "Error al registrarse: " + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp, android.R.color.transparent, R.color.error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Por que campo te gustaria ordenar? por defecto firebase te los va a ordenar del ulitmo puesto al primero, pero entiendo que queres ordenar desde el primer dato al utimo cierto ?

Comment: Quisiera que se ordenen como los estoy enviando, estuve informandome y parece que firebase no permite ordenarlos a mi manera ya que esta los va a ordenar siempre alfabéticamente :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con realtime database el orden es finito en tus consultas, por ejemplo, vas a poder ordenar por `orderBykey()` `orderByChild()` pero no vas a poder hacer los ordenes mas complejos para traer la información del servidor ya ordenada.

Hay dos opciones

1.- Es mudarte a Firestore donde todas estas consultas simples y compuestas las vas a poder hacer sin problema, por que podes hacer querys con where y hacerlas compuestas , eso te va a ser mucho mas facil (recomendado)

2.- Traer esa informacion como la traes ahora y hacer el filtro del lado del cliente, por ejemplo, traes la información, y una vez llega aplicarle un sort del lado del cliente, si usas kotlin podes hacerlo facil con `miLista.sortBy { ... }`

sino deberias usar un `Comparator` para hacer el sort mas complejo o simplemente `Collection.sort(miLista)` si fuera mas sencillo

Comment: Gracias Gastón por las recomendaciones, los de las consultas lo estoy realizando ahora; en la imagen se ve que estoy en Firestore y el punto es si,  ¿esos campos como se se envían a Firestore, se pueden ordenar a mi gusto o quedan así(ordenados alfabéticamente) sin poder modificarse?

Comment: Los datos van a ordenarse de una forma en firebase, vos lugo tenes que generar las querys para traer esos datos como vos queres y mostrarle al cliente, si te sirvio la respuesta podes marcarla como correcta, un saludo

Comment: Gracias, ya me quedó mas claro, otro saludo genio.